# Firebase analytics session duration calculation error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase analytics is calculating session duration's wrongly.
As per documentation, session times out after app is put in background for 30 min, if app is maximised after 30 min, then new session is generated and all the events are attributed to new session id.
But when i maximise app after 30 min, new events generated instantly are attributed to old session and new session is generated after some time, thus giving wrong session duration of old session.
How to fix this issue?